# develop iphone apps using adobe flash..?

Tags: iphone, air, flash-cs5

I want to develop iphone app using adobe flash..i googled these topic.i saw some people are saying that you cannnot develop for Iphone using flash because apple banned the flash on iphone...

but here on the adobe site :- 
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/logged_in/abansod_iphone.html

They are saying that you can develop for iphone using the flash 10.1 and Adobe AIR 2.5...so i am bit confused..
can we develop using flash or not?? (can we submit the app to app store??)

If yes,any site for good tutorials on using flash on iphone..?

Comment: On which planet have you been for the last half decade ? ;-)

Comment: the same planet on which you are..:-D

Answer (score 4):

Adobe was developing functionality to export a flash application to .ipa format fro CS5, and just before the release, Apple released new guidelines saying that using 3rd party programs to make apps was not allowed. However, in the last couple months, Apple again revised the guidelines and the functionality became available again.

This: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/packagerforiphone/

and this: http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/downloads.html

should have all the programs you need.

Here is a simple tutorial to show the basics on how to get your app compiled for testing: http://vimeo.com/groups/creativeapps/videos/9224055

Comment: What are you looking to program? A game? Or do you just want to learn general action script?

Comment: I would start by learning JavaScript, since both are dialects of the language ECMAScript. You can learn that here: http://www.echoecho.com/javascript.htm If you want to jump straight in to ActionScript, Kirupa has a very goog tutorial that starts from animation in Flash. http://www.kirupa.com/developer/flash/index.htm